# Maya python, get light type?

Tags: python, maya

I need to select the lights in my scene by type. PointLights, DirectionalLights, etc.

Selecting all lights is easy:

```
lights=cmds.ls(lights=True)

        for light in lights:  
        print light
```

But how can I select all the Point lights in that array?

I have tried:

```
type = cmds.getAttr(light + '.type')
```

but 'type' is not an attribute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This will do it.

```python
lights = cmds.ls(lights=True)

for light in lights:  
    light_type = cmds.nodeType(light)
    print(light_type)
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate on your array and filter it this way for example:

`` if(`nodeType $lightShape` == 'pointLight') { } ``

You can check Maya nodes list here: http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/Nodes/index.html

Comment: thanks! That is mel, isn't it? How to do this in python?

Comment: found it." type = cmds.nodeType(light)"

Comment: Ah yeah sorry about that :) You should maybe avoid assigning on `type` python built-in, you may have some surprise later if you want to use it.